# React - Promise - "this" is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, es6-promise

I'm sure this is a beginner question, but actually I can't figure out, why `this` is `undefined`.
But let's start from the beginning. I'm using `react` with `react-redux` to load data. In this special case I first want to load all positions of a project and then load the verfication files. That are 2 queries, so I want to be sure, that the positions are loaded completely before start loading the verifications. So I thought - oohh, let's use a `promise` here.

It starts with the method `loadVerifications(event)`. In this method, the method `loadProjectPositions(event)` is being called. I can see that the project positions are loaded correctly. 
When the positions are loaded it should load then the verification files (`.then(()...`).
Actually in this `.then()` method, `this` is undefined, but why?

[image]

```
class Kundenkommunikation extends Component {
  constructor(p) {
    super(p);
    this.state = {
    };

    this.loadProjectPositions = this.loadProjectPositions.bind(this);
    this.loadVerifications = this.loadVerifications.bind(this);
  }

  loadProjectPositions(event) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.props.getProjektPositionenByProjektIdForModulId(13, event.value);
      resolve(this)
    })
  }

  loadVerifications(event) {
    this.loadProjectPositions(event)
    .then(() => {
      this.props.projektpositionen && Object.values(this.props.projektpositionen).map((position) => {
        if(position.nachweis != null) {
          this.props.createBericht(position.nachweis.id,'SherpaVerbinder');
        }
      });
    })
  }
```

**UPDATE:**

Even when I'm bind `loadVerifications` in the constructor, it doesn't work. `this` stays `undefined`.

Comment: I think you have to bind your `loadVerifications` function as well.

Comment: if you define `loadVerifications` as `loadVerifications = (event) => { ... }` everything will work, you need to bind `this`

Comment: Even when I'm bind loadVerifications in the constructor, it doesn't work. this stays undefined.

Comment: Do you use bind like this: `this.loadVerifications = this.loadVerifications.bind(this);`?

Comment: Yes, as I wrote above.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, Your code looks correct, this is how you created it, are you sure that you're editing the right file or compile the project after edit? Do you see the bind line in source panel in dev tools when the debugger paused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for all hints and tipps. Lately it turned out, that Chrome did not show the data for whatever reason, but the data was available. I could find out by simply add an `console.log(this.props)` into the code, then it showed me all `props` and I was able to see that `this` is not `undefined`.

But the real issue was then, that the data was not loaded at this time. So I needed to add a `then` into the method `loadProjectPositions` to be sure, that the data is returned before resolving the `Promise`.

```
loadProjectPositions(event) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      this.props.getProjektPositionenByProjektIdForModulId(13, event.value)
      .then(() => {
        resolve(this)
      });
    })
}
```

After adding this, all data was loaded correctly at that time and then all worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bind(this) method for loadVerifications to get a component's context from the external function or 
Another is arrow functions loadVerifications= (event) => {...}

Comment: Even when I'm bind loadVerifications in the constructor, it doesn't work. this stays undefined.

Comment: Use arrow function.

Comment: If you starting using es6 feature, You wont face such issue.